# Closed form expression for $\sum_{k=0}^m{ n+2k \choose 1+2k}$

Tags: combinatorics

Can we get a closed form expression for

$f(m,n) = \sum_{k=0}^m{ n+2k \choose 1+2k}$,

for $m\ge 0, n>1$? I am interested in this expression, as it appeared in one of the problems I was solving. I have tried to see if the sequence has any pattern, but couldn't get any idea.

Answer (score 2):

Since 
$$\sum_{j=0}^{v}\binom{n+j}{j+1}=-1+\binom{n+1+v}{n}$$
we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{n+2k}{1+2k}&=&\sum_{j=0}^{2m}\binom{n+j}{1+j}-\sum_{j=0}^{2m-1}\binom{n+j}{1+j}+\sum_{j=0}^{2m-2}\binom{n+j}{1+j}-\ldots\\&=&\sum_{h=0}^{2m}(-1)^h\left(-1+\binom{n+1+2m-h}{n}\right)\\&=&-1+\sum_{h=0}^{2m}\binom{n+1+2m-h}{n}(-1)^h\tag{1}\end{eqnarray*}$$
hence your sum is a binomial coefficient times a fast converging hypergeometric function:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{n+2k}{1+2k}=\binom{n+1+2m}{n}\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(1,-1-2m;-1-2m-n;-1\right)\tag{2}$$
where the second factor in the RHS can be computed through the Gauss continued fraction, despite not having a "nice" closed form.

Comment: Can you tell me what $_2F_1()$ means or stands for?

Comment: @Shash: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function

Answer (score 0):

**There is no a very nice closed form for this series but I can provide a shortcut with less complexity**

$ S = \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{n+2k}{2k+1} $
$ S = \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{n+2k}{n-1} $  Since $ \binom{n+2k}{2k+1} = \binom{n-1+2k+1}{n-1} $

We take $ S = S_{n-1} $ Symbolically.

$$
\begin{matrix}
S & =  &  -\binom{n}{n} +\binom{n+1}{n} - ... -\binom{n+2m}{n} +\binom{n+2m+1}{n}  \\
  & =  &  \sum_{k=0}^{2m+1} (-1)^{k+1} \binom{n+k}{n} \ \small{Since} \ \binom{n+2k}{n-1} = -\binom{n+2k}{n} +\binom{n+2k+1}{n} \\
S & = &  -\binom{n}{n-2} +\binom{n+1}{n-1} - ... -\binom{n+2m}{n-2} +\binom{n+2m+1}{n-1}  \\
  & = &  \sum_{k=0}^{m} \left\{\binom{n+2k+1}{n-1}-\binom{n+2k}{n-2}\right\}  \small{Since} \binom{n+2k}{n-1} = \binom{n+2k+1}{n-1} -\binom{n+2k}{n-2} \\
2S & = &   \color{blue} {\sum_{k=0}^{m} \left\{\binom{n+2k+1}{n}-\binom{n+2k}{n}\right\}} + \color{red} {\sum_{k=0}^{m} \left\{\binom{n+2k+1}{n-1}-\binom{n+2k}{n-2}\right\}} \\
2S & = &  \sum_{k=0}^{m} \left\{\color{blue}{\binom{n+2k+1}{n}}+\color{red}{\binom{n+2k+1}{n-1}}\right\} - \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n+2k}{n}} - \color{red}{\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n+2k}{n-2}}\\
\end{matrix}$$

Since $\binom{n+2k+1}{n}+\binom{n+2k+1}{n-1} = \binom{n+2k+2}{n}$

$ 2S = \underset{0}{\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{n+2k+2}{n} - \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{n+2k+2}{n}}} + \binom{n+2m+2}{n} -\binom{n}{n} -S_{n-2} $

Wich gives:

$ 2^2S_{n-1} = 2\binom{n+2m+2}{n} -2\binom{n}{n} - 2S_{n-2} $

More general term:

$ 2^3S_{n-1} = 2^2\binom{n+2m+2}{n} -2^2\binom{n}{n} +2\binom{n+2m+2}{n-1} -2\binom{n}{n-1}  - 2S_{n-3} $

If we consider the initial case n=1:

$ 2S_0 = 2\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{2k+1}{2k+1} = 2\sum_{k=0}^m 1 = 2m+2 = n+m+2-n = \binom{n+2m+2}{1} -\binom{n}{1} $

We get the reccurence:

$$
\begin{matrix}
2^{n}S_{n-1} &  = & 2^{n-1}\binom{n+2m+2}{n} -2^{n-1}\binom{n}{n} -2^{n-2}\binom{n+2m+2}{n-1} +2{n-2}\binom{n}{n-1}  + ... \pm2S_0 \\
2^{n}S_{n-1} & = & 2^{n-1}\binom{n+2m+2}{n} -2^{n-1}\binom{n}{n} -2^{n-2}\binom{n+2m+2}{n-1} +2{n-2}\binom{n}{n-1}  + ... \pm\binom{n+2m+2}{1} \mp\binom{n}{1} + \color{blue}{1} - \color{red}{1} \\
2^{n+1}S_{n-1} &  = & 2^{n}\binom{n+2m+2}{n} -2^{n-1}\binom{n+2m+2}{n-1} + ... \mp \color{blue}{\binom{n+2m+2}{0}} \\
               & &  -2^{n}\binom{n}{n} +2^{n-1}\binom{n}{n-1} - ... \pm \color{red} {\binom{n}{0}} \\
\end{matrix}
$$

Formally:

$ 2^{n+1}S_{n-1}  = 2^{n}\binom{n+2m+2}{n} -2^{n-1}\binom{n+2m+2}{n-1} + ... \mp\binom{n+2m+2}{0}  - (-2+1)^{n} $

$ 2^{n+1}S_{n-1} = 2^{n}\binom{n+2m+2}{n} -2^{n-1}\binom{n+2m+2}{n-1} + ... \mp\binom{n+2m+2}{0} - (-1)^{n} $

$$ 2^{n+1}S_{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}  \left\{(-1)^k* 2^{n-k}*\binom{n+2m+2}{n-k} \right\} -(-1)^{n} $$

---

Let's try with some values:

$n=2,m=4$

$S =\sum_{k=0}^4 \binom{2+2k}{2k+1} = 2 +4 +6 +8 +10 = 30$

$2^{2+1}S_1 = \sum_{k=0}^{2} \left\{ (-1)^k * 2^{(2-k)} \binom{2+2*4+2}{2-k} \right\} -1 = 66*4 -12*2 +1 -1 = 240$

$ = 2^3S = 8*30$

This fits perfecly with $m \gg  n$ but what if $2m$ is smaller than $n$.

---

$$
\begin{matrix}
2^{n+1}S_{n-1} & = & \sum_{k=0}^{n} {(-1)^k 2^{n-k}\binom{n+2m+2}{n-k}} -(-1)^{n} \\
               & = & \sum_{k=0}^{n+2m+2} {(-1)^{n+k+1} 2^{k}\binom{n+2m+2}{k}} - \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+2m+2} {(-1)^{k-n} 2^{k}\binom{n+2m+2}{k}}  -(-1)^{n} \\
               & & (-1)^{n+2m+2}-(-1)^{n} + \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+2m+2} {(-1)^{k-n+1} 2^{k}\binom{n+2m+2}{k}}  \\
\end{matrix}
$$

With simplification,

$$ S = \sum_{k=0}^{2m+1} {(-1)^{k} 2^{k}\binom{n+2m+2}{n+k+1}} $$

or

$$ S = \sum_{k=0}^{2m+1} {(-1)^{k} 2^{k}\binom{n+2m+2}{2m+1-k}} $$

A slick transformation gives a fascinating property for the fourth column of the triangle $m=1$:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\sum_{k=0}^1 \binom{n+2k}{2k+1} &  = & \sum_{k=0}^{3} {(-1)^{k} 2^{k}\binom{n+4}{n+k+1}}  \\ 
\binom{n}{1} + \binom{n+2}{3} &  =  & \binom{n+4}{n+1} -2\binom{n+4}{n+2} +4\binom{n+4}{n+3} -8\binom{n+4}{n+4}  \\ 
n + \binom{n+2}{3} &  =  & \binom{n+4}{3} -2\binom{n+4}{2} +4(n+4) -8  \\ 
\binom{n+2}{3} &  =  & \binom{n+4}{3} -2\binom{n+4}{2} +3n+8  \\ 
\end{matrix}
$$

---

We try with n=7

$$
\begin{matrix}
\binom{7+2}{3} &   = & 84 \\
 &  = & \binom{7+4}{3} -2\binom{7+4}{2} +3(7)+8 \\
 &  = & 165 -2*55 +29 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

---

Hence, for every column $m$ smaller than $n/2$, every partial sum $P_l$ can be written as:

$$
\begin{matrix}
P_l &   = & \sum_{k=l}^m \binom{n+2k}{2k+1}  \\
 &  = & \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{n+2k}{2k+1} - \sum_{k=0}^{l-1} \binom{n+2k}{2k+1}  \\
 &  =  & \sum_{k=0}^{2m+1} {(-1)^{k} 2^{k}\binom{n+2m+2}{2m+1-k}} -  \sum_{k=0}^{2l-1} {(-1)^{k} 2^{k}\binom{n+2l}{2l-1-k}} \\
\end{matrix}
$$

Which is quite a magnificient property (at least for me)